# Return WCF Custom Fault Exception

Tags: wcf

I am having bit of trouble returning custom fault exception from wcf service.  The client application talking to wcf service gets – contract mismatch error.
Here is my fault contract defined in the service:

```
public partial class Fault
{
    string codeField;
    string messageField;
    string detailsField;
}
```

On error in the service I am creating custom fault exception as following:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception exception, MessageVersion version, ref Message       refMessage)
{
      mynamespace.Fault customFault = new mynamespace.Fault()
      {
           code = "Service Error",
           message = "Error Message",
           details = "Error Message"
      };

      FaultException<mynamespace.Fault> faultexception = new   FaultException<mynamespace.Fault>( customFault );

      MessageFault messageFault = faultexception.CreateMessageFault();

      refMessage = Message.CreateMessage( version, messageFault, faultNamespace );
}
```

This code causes contract mismatch error in client. Can anyone please help me finding what is wrong?

Comment: Problem might be somewhere else , can you put a break point in ProvideFault and see

Answer (score 3):

Specify what type of fault you need to return (for example, create a UserMismatchFault class), then throw it like so:

```
throw new FaultException<UserMismatchFault>(myFault);
```

Answer (score 3):

Steps to create a custom fault contract

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/jpsmit/archive/2007/03/21/wcf-fault-contracts.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What is `faultNamespace`? The third parameter of `CreateMessage` should be action (`faultException.Action`). Also don't forget that your `Fault` class must be valid `DataContract` - in case of default serialization members must be `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this [example on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/ExtendingWCF_PartI.aspx) can help you