# WCF: How to Pass Database Errors to client

Tags: c#, .net, sql

We have MVC4 and WCF based web application.

Due to client requirements we are forced to raise errors from the stored procedures instead of having them correct the database schema... anyways.

We are using SQL server 2008, and using RaiseError method in the procedure to return these errors.

Errors are like:

- Record already exist
- Record deleted.
- etc.

Service --calls-- DataManager --calls-- DataAccess (Error) -- invokes procedure.

some pointers would be very helpful as in how the errors can be passed down to the UI. 
How can these errors be brought into the service layer from the Data Access Layer?

Comment: You can add ErrorCode and ErrorMessage to your data contract and fill those values whenever there is error. Whether you raise the error on the service or on the database , you need to manipulate it on the service or business logic anyway

Comment: You need to make the exception a [FaultContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx). This way it can be caught on the client side. Something like `catch(FaultException<SQLException>)`.

Comment: like the Fault Contract will give it a try..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Return a custom SOAP fault that the caller can use to distinguish these errors from successful service responses and other errors as needed.

Catch the SQL exceptions, and return the custom fault in a global error handler (i.e. an [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) and a related [IServiceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx)) for the service.

MSDN has [a helpful overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx) of service error handling that speaks to these options.  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6110873/1810429) is a good resource too.